# VLC Media Player Green Line

Tags: vlc, 14.10

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 64bit and the latest version of VLC media player, when I play a video (MP4, MKV AVI etc... it doesn't matter) at the bottom of the screen there is a green line[image]
It isn't an issue with my OS, YouTube, and the default media player work fine. Has anyone else had this issue? and if so is there a fix or is it just a software bug?

Comment: This looks similar to the green lines that VLC renderes at the lower or right border when the video stream has an odd resolution.

Comment: Standard 1280x720 in an MKV container.

Comment: This may be related to hardware accelerated video decoding and/or rendering. You can try to disable it in the settings in two places: on the “video” panel (called “Overlay video output”) and [on the “input & codecs” panel](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/03/05/how-to-enable-gpu-accelerated-decoding-in-vlc/).

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks. If you post that as an answer I will vote up your answer so you can get reputation

Answer (score 37):

Open vlc and then go to preferences > video > select in the output "X11 video output" (you can mess with this to find the one that works best for you).

That's it :P

Comment: It worked. 2022 menu is : Tools >> Preferences >> Video >> Output. Also in my ubuntu 20 fresh intall, the exact option was : X11 Video Output (XCB)

Comment: Also you have to reopen the video after saving the preference if that is not obvious.

Answer (score 20):

Ctrl-P/Preferences/Video/Output.

Choosing **OpenGL GLX Video output (XKB)**  should solve this problem.

[image]

At the same time, that change should also improve appearance of subtitles.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

A good idea might be also:

Tools menu -> Preferences -> Video -> Uncheck "Accelerated Video Output (Overlay") (as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/550265/47206).)

Comment: I picked `X11 video output (XCB)`. I had a green part appearing at the top of the video, and now it disappeared. Good idea changing this setting.

Answer (score 8):

Open VLC
Go to Tools menu -> Preferences -> Video -> Uncheck 'Use hardware YUV-> RGB Conversons' Restart VLC

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it fixes the problem without a performance loss.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following options -

1. Tools menu –> Preferences –> Video –> Choose OpenGL under Output options –> Restart VLC.
2. Tools menu -> Preferences -> Video -> Uncheck "Accelerated Video Output (Overlay") -> Restart VLC.

Comment: Thank you. I have done the first step, but cannot find "Use hardware YUV>RGB conversions" to uncheck it for the second. So far, the green line has gone but the video is small and in bottom left corner.

Comment: I have changed the second step accordingly. Try pressing `c` when the video is playing and let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid the video is still small and in the bottom left corner. Pressing c changes the shape but not the size.

Comment: Ok. Instead of OpenGL try OpenGL GLX or something else in the Output options.

Comment: Selecting X11 Video Output in Output options may also do the trick.

Comment: This now works using OpenGL GLX and X11 Video Outputs.

Answer (score -2):

To get rid of green line at the bottom of VLC player , minimize VLC and click on the extended settings tab. Click on the video effects tab Then click on the crop tab Then change the bottom setting to 1 All done green line is gone:)"

And to get rid of the top green line just change the top setting to 2.

Answer (score -3):

To get rid of green line at the bottom of VLC player!!

Minimize VLC and click on the extended settings tab.
Click on the video effects tab
Then click on the crop tab
Then change the bottom setting to 1
All done green line is gone:)

Comment: This is not solving but hiding the problem!