# Ubuntu 15.04 : Green spots during video playback

Tags: 15.04, ati, xorg, lenovo, vlc

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a brand new Lenovo G50 laptop (with AMD Radeon graphics). I installed VLC to play HD video. Irrespective of the type of video, I am seeing green spots in the videos. See screenshot below.[image]

I tried the default player in Ubuntu and it is also giving the same error. Do I need to configure X11 ? Or is there any specific configuration needed for the AMD graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> Display

Uncheck "Accelerated Video Output(Relay)" as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541100/vlc-media-player-green-line)